# Assign Web Service method to ItemSource of ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, azure, xamarin

I need to consume a Azure Mobile Service in my application and I add Azure Mobile Client SDK in my project. In order to implement web service in my project, I set up my AzureService class like this-

```
    public partial class AzureService 
    {
        static AzureService defaultInstance = new AzureService ();

        MobileServiceClient client;

        IMobileServiceTable<modelLifeStyleDiets> modelLifeStyleDietsTable;

        public AzureService ()
        {
            this.client = new MobileServiceClient(url);

            this.modelLifeStyleDietsTable = client.GetTable<modelLifeStyleDiets>();

        }

        public static AzureService DefaultManager{      
            get{
                return defaultInstance;
                }
            private set{ 
                defaultInstance = value;
            }
        }

        public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient{
            get{ return client;}
        }

        public bool IsOfflineEnabled{
            get{ return modelLifeStyleDietsTable is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.IMobileServiceSyncTable<modelLifeStyleDiets>; }
        }


        public async Task<ObservableCollection<modelLifeStyleDiets>> GetTodoItemsAsync (bool syncItems = false)
        {
            try {

                IEnumerable<modelLifeStyleDiets> items = await modelLifeStyleDietsTable
                    .Where(Item => !(Item.done)).ToEnumerableAsync ();

                return new ObservableCollection<modelLifeStyleDiets> (items);
            } catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe) {
                Debug.WriteLine (@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.WriteLine (@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }


        public async Task SaveTaskAsync (modelLifeStyleDiets item)
        {
            if (item.id == null) {
                await modelLifeStyleDietsTable.InsertAsync (item);
            } else {
                await modelLifeStyleDietsTable.UpdateAsync (item);
            }
        }
    }
```

The model for my service is as given below-

```
    public class modelLifeStyleDiets
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string itemName { get; set; }
        public bool done{ get; set;}
    }
```

I have ListView and I need to get the data from service and assign it to ItemSource of ListView.
I tried this as -
    listof_lifestyleDiets.ItemsSource=AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync();

But in above code I am getting error of missing type casting. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **await** the async Task.

```
listof_lifestyleDiets.ItemsSource = await AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync();
```

You also need to make sure you're binding against the property you want to display.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding itemName}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Or if you're building your UI programatically

```
nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "itemName");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. But My ListView is like- **ListView listof_lifestyleDiets=new ListView {
   RowHeight=30,
   IsVisible=false,
   HeightRequest=150,
  };**

Comment: I really don't know, How to bind itemName in such case.

Comment: Do you have an ItemTemplate and a label?

Comment: Ok. Let me customise my ListView.

Comment: Now My ListView is like- ListView **ListView listof_lifestyleDiets=new ListView {
   RowHeight=30,
   IsVisible=false,
   HeightRequest=150,
   ItemTemplate=new DataTemplate (typeof(lifestyleDietsCell)),
   ItemsSource=AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync(),
  };** and its template is like -

Comment: **public class lifestyleDietsCell:ViewCell
 {
  public lifestyleDietsCell ()
  {var nameLabel = new Label () {
    FontFamily = "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
    FontSize = 18,
    TextColor = ColorResources.TextColor,
    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
   };
   nameLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "itemName");
   var cellLayout = new StackLayout {
    Spacing = 20,
    Padding = new Thickness (10, 5, 10, 5),
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Children = { nameLabel }
   };this.View = cellLayout; }
 }** but error is still there.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DinePerfect.modelLifeStyleDiets>>' to `System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You're still not awaiting the call to `AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync();` that is why it's complaining about trying to convert Task<T> to T. You need to either call `await AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync();` or `AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync().Result`. But I wouldn't recommend the second option.

Comment: **ItemsSource=AzureService.DefaultManager.GetTodoItemsAsync().Result** This line shows System.TypeInitializationException.